# Firebase Node.js cant find value in /verify/*/linked

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, lua, roblox

I got issue with firebase in node.js

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPqek.png)
here is image. I got roblox game and I wish to use the API in node.js with own verify bot..
So I coded it to make discord id first then linked like /verify/discordid/linked and then it return value. But in game I can't find discord id and I find it by knowing only linked value.

in part in verified we can see it have user id what is unknown and we got only body.linked so I need get from body.linked user.id..
Can someone send me code or explain how can I do it if it's even possible?

My script:

```
app.get("/api/verify/:target/:rbxid", function(req, res) {
    async function update(target, rbxid) {
        var { body } = await snekfetch.get(`${config.firebaseURL}verified/${target}.json`)
        //console.log(body)
        //console.log(`${config.firebaseURL}/verified/${target}.json`)
        if (!body) {
            return res.json({"verify": false})
        }
        var { body } = await snekfetch.get(`https://users.roblox.com/v1/users/${body.linked}`)
        if (body.id == rbxid) {
            return res.json({"verify": true})
        } else {
            return res.json({"verify": false})
        }
    }
    update(req.params.target,req.params.rbxid)
})
```

(script not done due idk how to do it as I said)
Also this script request at target discord id but normallz in game I know only rbx id and need find path to discord id.

Comment: `snekfetch` is a very outdated library. You should update to a modern equivalent like the `fetch` API (see [here for examples](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#common-usage), no need for the import line though).

Comment: What is `:target` and `:roleid` in your URL? What is `interaction`?

Comment: I will send soon updated version where is more understable. Target is id of discord what muss be found roleid is also role id ignore that one i will send verify enpoint if u can find discord id i can find by my self roleid..

Comment: Also im not planning to go to other library due even on other i didn't found any infos to that issue